# Matching and Routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I generated a controller and changed the routes but opening the links yields errors on my local server.

**Generating controller and routes**

```
rails generate controller StaticPages home about team contact
```

**Change routes.rb**

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/about',    to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/team',     to: 'static_pages#team'
  match '/contact',  to: 'static_pages#contact'
end
```

The root path work but none of the 'about, 'team', or 'contact' links work. This is the error I get:

"You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option. If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router: Instead of: match "controller#action" Do: get "controller#action""

Why can't I use 'match'?

Comment: What Rails version are you using? In terminal, go to this rails project and do `rails -v`.

Comment: I was using 4.0. Using 'get' instead of 'match' solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[`match` method has been deprecated.](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5964)

Use `get` for GET and `post` for POST.

`get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'`

Comment: +1, the current version of [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) says nothing about `match` being deprecated. Good info!

Comment: Not deprecated (yet), only need to add the via: like user2062950 said.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `match`, you've gotta add a `via:` option:

```
match '/about',    to: 'static_pages#about', via: :get
match '/team',     to: 'static_pages#team', via: :get
match '/contact',  to: 'static_pages#contact', via: :get
```

You can also pass other HTTP verbs to `via:` if you need to, like `via: [:get, :post]`

Source: [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, you must specify the HTTP method by adding `via: :get` at the end of `match 'st' => 'controller#action`

And it's better to use `get '/home', to: 'static_pages#home'`

But, there is a problem, that your code doesn't follow RESTful, that only support 7 actions: index, new, edit, create, update, show and destroy.

These are 2 solutions:

**SOL 1**: Put them in different controller (homes, abouts..) and all of these controllers have action `index`.

**SOL 2**: If it's too much work, we can match them to `show` action. We use static_pages controller, and each page (home, about) will be a item.

The routes will look likes

`/static_pages/home
/static_pages/about`

I know it isn't good because of the prefix `static_pages`.

We can easily get rid of this by adding a custom routes at the end of routes file:

`get '/:id', to: 'static_pages#show'`

That's it. And if you think it's too much work (I think so too), check out this gem [High Voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage). Have fun.