# Rails 4 Routing static content

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

What I am trying to do is create an alias for Rails 4, having all the /image/[name] go to the real folder /assets/[name]. The reason I need to do this is because I am using jquery-ui which has /image/[picture] paths. The following below is what I have but it doesn't quite work for syntax reasons, but I think it's on the right track:

```
  match '/images/:name', to: => '/assets/:name'
```

I have found some ideas in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368933/matching-and-routes-in-rails) but all these examples require or use controller which I don't think are necessary in my case. I just want to have all /images/[image_name] links be an alias to the folder /assets/[image_name]. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [redirect](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection) directive in your `routes.rb`

```
get '/images/:name', to: redirect('/assets/%{name}')
```